# Grails 3 exclude Spring Boot AutoConfguration

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

As Grails 3 is build on top of Spring Boot it runs the standard AutoConfigurations. One of these (SolrAutoConfiguration) is causing problems as it conflicts with the version of Solr that I am using (5.0.0). In a Spring Boot application I can disable this configuration by passing the exclude flag i.e.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SolrAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApp
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Grails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotating your `Application` class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [SolrAutoConfiguration])` should work.

Comment: Is grails 3 app really using @ EnableAutoConfiguration - i thought grails 3 doesnt use autoconfiguration at all. - where's that magic ? how is auto configration getting kicked in, when we dont have @EnableAutoConfiguration on application class